# Adding color on bars of a barplot based on contribution to the total of each bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following image is a dataframe showing the immigration from each continent to a country. How can I plot a barplot showing the sum for each year, and on each bar show the contribution by each continent, by using different colors for each continent?

My code that got me so far is follows:

```
df_continent = df_can.groupby('Continent').sum()
years = df_continent.columns.tolist()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a clear example of the output you're expecting, but I'm sure you'll find that
The first example is simply a graph of yearly immigration numbers stacked by continent.
The second example is an example of a compositional graph for each continent by year.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
continent 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984
Africa 3951 4363 3819 2617 2639
Asiz 31025 34314 30214 24696 27274
Europe 39760 44802 42720 24638 22287
"Latin America" 13081 15215 16769 15427 13678
"Northern America" 9378 10030 9074 7100 6661
Oceania 1942 1839 1675 1018 878
'''

# df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.plot(x='continent', kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

percentage type

```
d = df[df.columns[1:]].div(df[df.columns[1:]].sum())
df1 = pd.concat([df[['continent']],d],1)
df1.set_index('continent', inplace=True)
df1
            1980    1981    1982    1983    1984
continent                   
Africa  0.039854    0.039462    0.036626    0.034664    0.035945
Asiz    0.312951    0.310357    0.289764    0.327117    0.371494
Europe  0.401061    0.405217    0.409702    0.326348    0.303567
Latin America   0.131949    0.137614    0.160821    0.204342    0.186306
Northern America    0.094596    0.090718    0.087023    0.094045    0.090728
Oceania 0.019589    0.016633    0.016064    0.013484    0.011959

df1.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]